# Alternate row color in css grid in vue

Tags: html, css, vue.js

Hi im making a vue component that displays a table of data and i need to style each row with an alterating background color.
This is the code of the component

```
<template>

    <div class="main-wrap">
        <div class="container">

            <header class="header">
                <div style="background-color:#0d1124"></div>
                <div class="flex-line-v head-all" style="background-color: #ff2e17;">
                    <div class="small-txt">Allarme</div>
                    <div class="big-txt">{{ data?.qtaAllarme }}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-line-v head-pre-all" style="background-color: #ffae47;">
                    <div class="small-txt">Pre-Allarme</div>
                    <div class="big-txt">{{ data?.qtaPreAllarme }}</div>
                </div>  
                <div class="flex-line-v head-lav" style="background-color: #44b94a;">
                    <div class="small-txt">Lavorazione</div>
                    <div class="big-txt">{{ data?.qtaLavorazione }}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-line-v head-prep" style="background-color: #00b9f2;">
                    <div class="small-txt">Preparazione</div>
                    <div class="big-txt">{{ data?.qtaPreparazione }}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-line-v head-avv" style="background-color: #ff00ff;">
                    <div class="small-txt">Avviamento</div>
                    <div class="big-txt">{{ data?.qtaAvviamento }}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-line-v head-inatt" style="background-color: #85878b;">
                    <div class="small-txt">Inattività</div>
                    <div class="big-txt">{{ data?.qtaInattivita }}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-line-v head-ferm" style="background-color: #0f2e93;">
                    <div class="small-txt">Fermo</div>
                    <div class="big-txt">{{ data?.qtaFermo }}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-line-v head-man" style="background-color: #603515   ;">
                    <div class="small-txt">Manutenzione</div>
                    <div class="big-txt">{{ data?.qtaManutenzione }}</div>
                </div>

                <div style="background-color:#0d1124"></div>
            </header>


            <template v-for="(cell, index) in data?.mainTable">
                <div class="cell">{{ cell.id ? cell.id : "" }}</div>
                <div class="cell">{{ cell.qtaAllarme ? cell.qtaAllarme : "" }}</div>
                <div class="cell">{{ cell.qtaPreAllarme ? cell.qtaPreAllarme : "" }}</div>
                <div class="cell">{{ cell.qtaLavorazione ? cell.qtaLavorazione : "" }}</div>
                <div class="cell">{{ cell.qtaPreparazione ? cell.qtaPreparazione : ""}}</div>
                <div class="cell">{{ cell.qtaAvviamento ? cell.qtaAvviamento : "" }}</div>
                <div class="cell">{{ cell.qtaInattivita ? cell.qtaInattivita : "" }}</div>
                <div class="cell">{{ cell.qtaFermo ? cell.qtaFermo : "" }}</div>    
                <div class="cell">{{ cell.qtaManutenzione ? cell.qtaManutenzione : "" }}</div>
                <div>LINK</div>
            </template>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>
```

This is the template for the Vue component. I have set my headers presetted then i use a vfor to create the rows to populate the table
This is the way i implemented the styling:

```
.container {
    display: grid; 
    grid-template-columns: max-content repeat(8, 1fr) 1fr ;
    gap: 1vw 1vw;
    font-size: var(--font-big); 
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 90vh;
}

.header {
    display: contents;
}

.header > div {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

.head-all { grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3; }
.head-pre-all { grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4; }
.head-lav { grid-area: 1 / 4 / 2 / 5; }
.head-prep { grid-area: 1 / 5 / 2 / 6; }
.head-avv { grid-area: 1 / 6 / 2 / 7; }
.head-inatt { grid-area: 1 / 7 / 2 / 8; }
.head-ferm { grid-area: 1 / 8 / 2 / 9; }
.head-man { grid-area: 1 / 9 / 2 / 10; }

.cell {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

As you can see I had to set the header to display content and i sticked it to the top so it wont scroll with the page. Now what i need to do is to style each rows with alternating colors, i tried this but all solutions I have found either wont work or will style only the cells and therefore look bad. What I want is to have the whole row The same color

Thanks

I have tried many ways like using :nth-of-type pseudo class to select each row like this

```
.table .cell:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: white;
}
.table .cell:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

But it does not work

Comment: The problem is that you do not have rows to style... Instead of using a <Template> tag, use a <div> with a class of row or something. Then you'll be able to work it out easy.

Comment: Hi ! Please [read the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). We can help you more easily if you make your code a snippet with the `<>` button. Your title says you want to give rows alternate background colors. Your code attempts to give cells alternate background colors. Maybe you are missing a `<div class="row">` surrounding each table row?

Comment: Yes I figured after posting the question but if i do not use template it wont display items correctyl, iv spun up a a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-nrq32j?file=src/App.vue